# Failover url configuration for Dynamic Endpoint

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Hi I am using Dynamic Endpoint feature in WSO2 API Manager - 2.6.0 to redirect to the appropriate backend service based on the parameter. Since I am using this feature, I have no option to configure my failover service. For instance, when one of my backend service is not responsive, then this failover service should be called. If I use fault flow mediator, how will I ask it to redirect to my failover service? Is it possible? Pls suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be helpful for someone. So I configured the fault flow mediator and used the below code snippet to achieve the failover. Thanks.

```
<send>
    <endpoint name="dynamicApiCalls--v1.0_APIproductionEndpoint">
    <http uri-template="https://myDomain.org.net/url"/>
    endpoint>
</send>
```

Created a blog on how to achieve this.
https://letsknowthingsfromblog.wordpress.com/2020/06/23/dynamic-endpoints-with-failover-in-wso2-api-manager/